# Finding the 2nd occurance's index of a string and that string should be the start of the line using python

Tags: python, string

I m trying to find the 2nd occurance's index of a string. String is present in a text file. I m able to get the 2nd occurance index using find() function in python.

Here, i need to find the index of string using 2 factors.
1) The string should be starting of the line.
2) It should be 2nd occurance in the whole file.
3) String may present in between the paragraphs, but i need to ignore those and find the index of only the string which starts with the new line.

Tried startwith() function as well. But i m able to match string on one query and retrieve the result but not able to find the logic for this problem.

This is the text file content. Consider "**vitae**" is the string, it is present inside the paragraph and i m able to get the index of each "**vitae**" string but not able to get it as the 2nd occurance which starts with the new line.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sollicitudin tortor et velit venenatis molestie. Morbi non nibh magna, quis tempor metus. 
Vivamus vehicula velit sit amet neque posuere id hendrerit sem venenatis. Nam vitae felis sem. Mauris ultricies congue mi, eu ornare massa convallis nec. 
vitae Donec volutpat molestie velit, scelerisque porttitor dui suscipit vel. Etiam feugiat feugiat nisl, vitae commodo ligula tristique nec. Fusce bibendum fermentum rutrum.
```

This code will get me the 1st and 2nd occurance's index.

```
i = st.find("vitae")
b = st.find("vitae", i+1)
print "this s 1st occurance",i
print "this s 2nd occurance",b
```

Tried this code as well but no luck !!

```
def find2(strng, ch, start):
    index = start
    while index < len(strng):
        print "inside while loop"
        if strng[index] == ch:
            print "inside if loop"
            return index
        index += 1
    return -1
```

Thanks in advance ! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking, could you try to clarify?

Comment: Suppose take an example , we need to identify the word in a text document. I have to get the second occurrence position (index- offset position) of that particular word which is starting in a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to search for `"\n"` as well.

```python
def find2(string, substring, start=0):
    return string.find(
        "\n" + substring,
        string.find("\n" + substring, start) + len(substring) + 1
    ) + 1
```

is an option. But I'd recommend a version that finds the n'th occurance directly:

```
def findnth(string, nth, substring, start=0):
    splitted = string[start:].split("\n" + substring, nth)
    if len(splitted) != nth + 1:
        raise ValueError("substring not found")
    return len(string) - len(splitted[-1]) - len(substring)
```